# Integrate pc-lint in notepad++

Tags: c, notepad++, pc-lint

Has anyone come across a way to integrate pc-lint with notepad++ ?
I have searched across the web but could not get a good answer.
A good solution would involve line jump to the mentioned line error.
Lint explanations for other languages are out there but I am particularly looking for a C environment.
Refined question thus stands that has anybody integrated pc-lint for a C code base in notepad++ ?

Answer (score 0):

I have researched the web but something with a nice "jump to the error" functionality is absent. If that is not available there is no point in integrating pc lint with notepad++. But this is something that gimpel needs to pay an ear to.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here we do not use the normal forum thread style of posts, but a single question followed by multiple answers style. If you wish to add information to your question then please edit the question, if you wish to discuss an answer, then use the *comment* link on that answer - in neither case should you add another answer as you have done here. Please read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in the help pages

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `NppExec-Plugin` to run the `lint-nt.exe` from `notepad++`. If you configure the Console Output Filter suitably to match your output format, you will have your `jump to the error` functionality integrated in `notepad++`.

Have fun with it!